# Java add Tree to ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, tree

Im trying to add each node of a Binary Search Tree to an ArrayList in order, I currently have this code...

```
private ArrayList<String> toArray(TreeNode<Comparable> root)
  {    
    ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
    if(root!= null)
      return null;
    inorder(root.getLeft());
    array.add(root.getValue());
    inorder(root.getRight());
    return array;
  }
```

but i get this error from running it...

```
Error: BSTree.java:64: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method add(java.lang.Comparable)
location: class java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.String>
```

thank you for any help.

Comment: What does your TreeNode class look like?

Comment: This method takes a tree of Comparable:s - there are a lot of Comparable:s that aren't Strings. Only Strings fits into the ArrayList. See?

Comment: how do i add comparables to an arraylist

Comment: ArrayList<String> -> ArrayList<Comparable>

Answer (score 1):

Would the following Generic method work for you?  I'm away from my compiler but solution should be something like this:

```
  private <T extends Comparable<T>> ArrayList<T> toArray(TreeNode<T> root)
  {    
    if(null == root)
      return null;

    ArrayList<T> array = new ArrayList<T>();
    inorder(root.getLeft());
    array.add(root.getValue());
    inorder(root.getRight());
    return array;
  }
```

This TreeNode seems similar to the class in this webpage:
[Some CS Class notes](http://grail.cba.csuohio.edu/~matos/notes/cis-265/lecture-notes/cis265-lecture-notes-binary-search-trees-DONE.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

I have used something like this

```
private void inorder(Node u){
            if( tree.isLeaf(u) ){
                arrayList.add(u);
            }else{
                Node v = tree.getLeft(u);
                invorder(v);

                arrayList.add(u);

                v = tree.getRight(v);
                invorder(v);
}
```